# Python Tensorflow Summarize Two Histograms Together

Tags: tensorboard

I was wondering if there is a way to summarize two histograms in tensorflow together and get something resembling the behavior of `tf.summary.histogram`. The reason is that I need to summarize batch logits for two different operations and I need the histograms to be "superimposed" so that I can compare their dynamics with respect to one another during training by only looking at the log file using `Tensorboard`.